# .htaccess Question mark allowing

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting, url-rewrite-module

Hello today i tried to rewrite few things, i tried to rewrite this:

```
www.example.com/index.php?title=how+do+man+live?
```

To:

```
www.example.com/posts/how+do+man+live?/
```

Now the problem is that the question mark appears only at url and when i post the $_GET variable(title..) its post everything but not the question mark.

i tried put in rewrite mdoe this:

```
RewriteRule post/([0-9א-בa-zA-Z+.`?]+)/?$ index.php?title=$1 [NC]
```

course that the Rewrite engine is on.
thank you guys, have wonderful day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to capture this value from `THE_REQUEST` variable to be able to capture `?` also. Use this rule in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+posts/(\S+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ index.php?title=%1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thank you very much. but now the url are sensetive to the appear of / in the end i mean:example/posts/how+are+you?/ work and example.com/posts/how+are+you? doesnt work

Comment: I think `[B]` should also be passed here: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/flags.html#flag_b

Comment: Actually I had tested with `B` and without `B` before posting this answer. With `B` flag `$_GET['title']`  becomes `how+do+man+live?/` and without `B` it comes `how do man live?/`