# allow non-query question marks "?" in URL/URI w/o encoding

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

## setup

we have the following directory structure on our HTTP/web server:

```
/questions/who?/
/questions/what?/
/happy? part. 01/
/happy? yet?/
/happy? yet? again? really?!/
```

## question

my question: is it possible to have the corresponding URIs/URLs with *unescaped/unencoded* question marks (`?`) resolve correctly?  e.g. the URL `http://test.org/happy? part. 01/` will resolve to `/happy? part. 01/` on the server. due to `?` signifying a query string, this is has been a pickle of a problem for me.

## background/research

as expected by default Apache treats the first `?` as the beginning of a query string.  so out of the box a URL of `http://test.org/happy? part. 01/` will be converted to a URI path `/happy` and query string  `part.01/`, resulting in a 404 since the path `/happy` does not exist.

most of the other answers/tips i have found in my research mainly deal with rewriting the URL *assuming that the `?` indicates a query string*, e.g.

- [.htaccess Question mark allowing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26433965/htaccess-question-mark-allowing)
- [Apache .htaccess: How to remove question mark from URL if not `?id=(.*)`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4881410/apache-htaccess-how-to-remove-question-mark-from-url-if-not-id)
- [htaccess rewrite rule, remove question mark](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13761125/htaccess-rewrite-rule-remove-question-mark)

however, in this case **we can assume that our HTTP server will not be receiving URLs with query strings**.

i realize that normally browsers/etc. will encode the URI before sending it to the server (e.g. `http://test.org/happy? part. 01/` will be sent to the server as `http://test.org/happy%3F%20part.%2001/`, though which characters are encoded [depends on the app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26707046/should-a-browser-encode-a-custom-uri-before-launching-an-app?rq=1) and their support for which URI standard version: [RFC2396](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2396) or [RFC3986](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986)).  but for this scenario the server may be getting unencoded URLs but never any URLs with query strings.

## my attempts

at first i thought a simple rule like this would suffice:

```
RewriteRule ([^\?]*?)\?([^\?]*?) $1\?$2 [NE,N]
```

here i am trying to repeatedly find all the `?`s and simply reinsert them into the URL unescaped. unfortunately the regular expression (and many variations) is not matching the URLs that contain `?`, instead only matching the encoded `?` value `%3F`. and even when it matches, the second capture group `$2` seems to always be empty. finally, the `\?` in the substitution string seems to be preventing anything after it from being written.

the above linked solutions led me to the fact that to check for the `?` i had to check `%{THE_REQUEST}` variable since Apache will strip the query string for other server variables/RewriteRules.  to that end i tried variations of this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]+\ \/([^\?]*?)\?([^\?]*?)\/?\ HTTP
RewriteRule ^(.*?)\?(.*?)$ $1\?$2 [NE,N]
```

while the regular expression of the `RewriteCond` is matching URIs with `?`, the `%2` in the `RewriteRule` causes an `Internal Server Error`, though without it i seem to have no way of accessing the part of the URL after the `?`.

finally, i also tried various things with `%{QUERY_STRING}` and `[QSA]` but still no luck.

thanks for taking a look.

Answer (score 2):

How about simply:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} !200
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1\%3F%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NE]
```

---

EDIT:

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(.*)\?(.*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%1\%3F%2 [L]

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1\%3F%{QUERY_STRING}? [L,NE]
```

Comment: thanks! this does work for cases when there is only a single `?`, though with multiple reserved characters (in this case `?`) in a URL it drops everything after the second `?`, including the 2nd `?`:
`http://test.org/happy? yet?/` returns `The requested URL /happy? yet was not found`

also, when the trailing `/` is left off the rewrite also fails:
`http://test.org/happy? part. 01/` becomes `http://test.org/happy%3f part. 01/? part. 01` and the server returns `The requested URL /happy was not found`.

1st problem seems more difficult, the 2nd perhaps just a small change, though still beyond me.

Comment: thx again @Jon Lin . the edit now works for 2 question marks in a URL but unfortunately 2 problems still:
- some URLs with 1 question mark do not work (404) w/o the trailing `/` e.g. `http://test.org/who?` and `http://test.org/questions/what?`
- some URLs with 1 question mark and no trailing `/` rewrite fine but now have the `?` character encoded in final browser URL e.g. `http://test.org/happy? part. 01` becomes `http://test.org/happy%3f part. 01`

the 2nd problem might be a browser thing but the 1st may have something to do with rules still.  hopefully almost there :) thanks again.

Comment: @JonLin - Can you examine the code am using this code through htaccess for replacing ascii %2f to ? - RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !^$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /$1?%{QUERY_STRING} [L,NC,R=301]